# Clone parent-child tree in PHP, start from child and avoid endless recursion

Tags: php, recursion, tree, clone

I have an object-oriented parent-child tree in PHP that I want to clone.
The difficult part is that the access to the tree is not always through the root, but sometimes through a child of the root, like this:

```
[Root]
  -- [Element1] START CLONE
       -- [Element3]
       -- [Element4]
  -- [Element2]
       -- [Element5]
```

**So what I want to do is to clone the entire tree, by calling `$new = clone $element1;`**

The __clone() method states that each of the children must also be cloned, and, if the illustrated situation occurs*, also the parent must be cloned.

** Root is explicitly set as parent in Element1, so the system can identify this situation and do something with it.*

The problem is that, starting the `clone` operation from Element1, Root must also be cloned. The cloning procedure for Root prescribes that all child elements must be cloned and therefore the `clone` operation for Element1 is called again, which then repeats the same cloning procedure, producing an endless loop.

Furthermore, the Root will not contain the first clone of Element1, but it will produce its own clone to add as a child. Element1 will then have Root as its parent, but Root will not have the same Element1 as a child.

I hope I presented the problem in a clear way and that someone can help me find a solution.

**EDIT:**

**Final solution:**

```
/**
 * The $replace and $with arguments allow a custom cloning procedure. Instead of
 * being cloned, the original child $replace will be replaced by $with.
 */
public function duplicate($replace = null, $with = null) {
    // Basic cloning
    $clone = clone $this;
    // If parent is set
    if(isset($this->parent)) {
        // Clone parent, replace this element by its clone
        $parentClone = $this->parent->duplicate($this, $clone);
        $clone->parent = $parentClone;
    }

    // Remove all children in the clone
    $clone->clear();

    // Add cloned children from original to clone
    foreach($this->getChildren() as $child) {
        if($child === $replace)
            // If cloning was initiated from this child, replace with given clone
            $childClone = $with;
        else
            // Else duplicate child normally
            $childClone = $child->duplicate();

        // Add cloned child to this clone
        $clone->add($childClone);
    }

    return $clone;
}
```

Comment: What data structure are you using? Objects with parent-children properties? Arrays?

Comment: I'm using arrays to list all children of an object. In the described situation, Element1 also has a 'parent' property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, simplify your example:

```
[Root]
  -- [Element1] START CLONE
       -- [Element3]
```

Then differ between what you do, I think you have got *three* operations

- *public* clone method.
- A self-clone operation that returns a clone with children, but not the parent.
- A single-clone operation that returns a clone w/o children.

Code outside of your classes is using the public clone method. But the `__clone()` method *must* not use that method, otherwise you run into the circular looping problem you've described. So the `__clone()` implementation must use *other* methods.

Add a `cloneSelf` and `cloneSingle` method to your class, make them protected, so inherited classes can call them but they are not publicly available.

Then make use of them in the `__clone()` implementation:

```
public function clone()
{
    // clone the parent
    $parent = $this->getParent();
    $parentClone = $parent->cloneSingle();

    // clone all children of parent which includes $this
    $selfClone = NULL;
    foreach($parent->getChildren() as $child)
    {
        $childClone = $child->cloneSelf();
        if (!$selfClone && $child === $this)
            $selfClone = $childClone;
        $parentClone->addChild($childClone);

    }

    assert('$selfClone');

    return $selfClone;
}

public function __clone()
{
    $message = 'Clone operator is not allowed, use clone() method instead.';
    throw new BadMethodCallException($message);
}
```

These methods will also help you to clone in case there is no parent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think the reasoning is good, but according to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) the \_\_clone() method is called from the object _clone_, _after_ the standard shallow cloning has been completed. The object you get from the `clone $object` operation will not be $selfClone from this method.
Also because of this, we cannot compare each child of the parent with the current object using '===', since the clone is nowhere among the children of the parent of the original.

Comment: @RemiX: Yeah right I mixed it. However you can inversion the logic by providing your own public clone method instead, I edited the answer.

Comment: Ok, apart from the fact that you cannot call a method `clone()`, your answer was now very useful. I created a custom `duplicate()` method, which first calls the `clone` operator. Then it clones its parent and replaces itself with its clone. This allows for more recursion when the parent has yet another parent, AND I won't have to reinvent cloning (I can still use the `clone` operator).

I edited the final code into my question. Thanks for your help. Unless someone comes up with something that makes this solution look like crap, you'll get the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

What if you add a parameter tot the `__clone()` method? - let's call it `$called_from`

Based on the value of that parameter you know what to do:

- when the param has the default value 'external', or has the value `child` then clone was called from an external place, so you will call `__clone()` on parent with, sending 'child' as value
- when `__clone()` is finally called on root node with 'child' or 'external' value set to `$called_from`, it starts the real cloning process by calling `__clone()` with `$called_from` set to 'parent'

**Edit**

I was not aware of the builtin `clone` keyword. So, you could create a base class that all your tree objects are inheriting from - this class could have a `static`, variable that will indicate what clone has to act like

- when set to true, the real `clone` algorithm will be executed, otherwise, will `__clone()` the parent object
- the default value is `false`, and only the root node sets this to true, just before it starts cloning the children

This base class can also override the __clone() method, to implement this algorithm in a single place.

Comment: Sounds like a decent solution, except I don't know how to pass a parameter with the 'clone' operation. Is that even possible?

Comment: Ok, then one more hurdle: if I clone the parent like this: $this->parent = clone $this->parent (in the __clone() method), its parent will start cloning all its (still original) children (of which $this is one) but it will be another instance than $this itself. Going from child to parent and from parent back to child will get you to another clone of the same child.. any suggestions on that? Or is this unclear?